# Quicknode with any dApp?

Tags: solidity

Can I connect to ANY contract on the Ethereum mainnet using Quicknode? Or does Quicknode only support a subset of actual solidity contract endpoints using a rest API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quicknode provides, besides many other services, a REST API to interact with supported blockchain networks via JSON-RPC clients. This means that Quicknode can be used as a JSON-RPC Provider. For supported chains refer to their documentation, [here](https://www.quicknode.com/docs).

> In order for a software application to interact with the Ethereum blockchain - either by reading blockchain data or sending transactions to the network - it must connect to an Ethereum node. Every Ethereum client implements a JSON-RPC specification...

[ref](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/)

In order to interact with a smart contract, e.g. call a function for reading state, an client needs to send an `eth_call` method JSON-RPC request.

So now back to your question.

> Can I connect to ANY contract on the Ethereum mainnet using Quicknode?

If you mean by "connecting to a contract", to interact with a contract: YES, you can interact with any contract via Quicknode calling their respective API endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @norym. So if I wish to make a swap on Balancer, I can use Quicknode and just provide an appropriate JSON request payload for the contract function I want to call?

Comment: I do not know about Balancer and I think if Balancer provides swaps for tokens, it will likely provide a dApp on which you can connect with your wallet in order to interact with the contract/swap your tokens. But, yes you will be able to interact with Balancer's contracts as I explained.

Comment: Btw just for clarity, when you say Quicknode provides a REST API for interacting with supported blockchain networks via JSON-RPC, does this mean I make an API request (say HTTP) and then they in turn create a request for the JSON-RPC? I never need to create a JSON-RPC request myself?

Comment: Correct, you do not need to care about the JSON-RPC request handling.

Comment: Awesome. And if I use a library like `web3js` then I am in fact directly constructing the JSON-RPC calls again?

Comment: Web3js is a wrapper library enabling the interaction with chain and constracts via HTTP, websockets, etc via a node, i.e. JSON-RPC, provider. So, when using Web3js you will not construct JSON-RPC requests yourself. In fact, you can use Quicknode as node/ JSON-RPC provider in web3js and would not need to write any JSON-RPC request yourself.